# Riverpod, Flutter - how to change Checkbox state by index

Tags: flutter, riverpod, checkboxlist

There is a CartCheckbox widget (object) with the true state. It is added to the CartItemWidget from which the List is then formed.
Since a List from a CartItemWidget with the same object is added to ListView.builder (as I understand it), when you click on a checkbox, all checkboxes in the list become inactive..

added a provider that could return Map key and value to me

`final checkboxesProvider = StateProvider<Map<String, bool>>((ref) => {'Checkbox1': true});`

then this..

```
class CartCheckbox extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CartCheckbox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final checkboxes = ref.watch(checkboxesProvider);
  //  ref.watch(selectAllProvider);

    return Column(
      children: [
        ...checkboxes.entries.map((entry) {
          return Checkbox(
            value: entry.value,
            activeColor: AppColors.main,
            onChanged: (bool? value) {
              ref.watch(checkboxesProvider.notifier).state[entry.key] = value!;
              ref.refresh(selectAllProvider.notifier).state = ref.read(checkboxesProvider.notifier).state.values.every((v) => v);
            },
          );
        },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

sheet is created here..

```
  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: response.data.products.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return CartItemWidget(
                        key: ValueKey<String>(
                            response.data.products[index].price.price),
                        product: response.data.products[index],
                        cartState: state,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

the result was needed like this:

When we go to the cart, all checkboxes are active.
After clicking on one of the checkboxes, this checkbox and “select all” will become inactive.
When the last checkbox becomes active, "select all" also becomes active

how can you make each individual checkbox active or inactive (I think through index) based on this code)... maybe I’m wrong

```
Consumer selectAllButton() {
return Consumer(
  builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
    final selectAll = ref.watch(selectAllProvider);

    return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Checkbox(
                  value: selectAll,
                  activeColor: AppColors.main,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    ref.read(selectAllProvider.notifier).state = value!;
                    ref.read(checkboxesProvider.notifier).state = ref
                        .read(checkboxesProvider.notifier)
                        .state
                        .map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, !selectAll));
                  },
                ),
                Insets.gapW8,
                const Text(
                  "Обрати всі",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: AppColors.textGray80),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  },
);
```

}

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
return Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, child) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.line),
        ),
      ),
      child: ProductPushWrapper(
        product: product,
        child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                       const CartCheckbox(),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        avatarImage(),
                        Insets.gapW20,
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: Cross
```

Comment: Can you include your `selectAllProvider` and `CartItemWidget`

Comment: added


,
            
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: response.data.products.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return CartItemWidget(
                        key: ValueKey<String>(
                            response.data.products[index].price.price),
                        product: response.data.products[index],
                        cartState: state,
                      );
                    },

Comment: thanks, I was  looking for `selectAllProvider`

Comment: maybe a redefinition would help me ==
and hash code, but I still don’t fully understand how to do it all correctly..

Comment: Ok, let share a minimal version how you can do it.

Comment: Stop using StateProvider, especially on a List.  You'll never get notifications when you update the value! Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice..
I'm sorry, but I haven't been programming for very long, and therefore I don't know quite enough about conservative technologies.
I would be grateful for some practical advice

Comment: we just took a project that uses this provider... before that we did it on cubit

Answer (score 0):

I am just using `checkboxesProvider` to control the selection including select all.

While `Map` override duplicate key's value, you can take this advantage on updating item.

```dart
ref
    .watch(checkboxesProvider.notifier)
    .update((state) => {...state, entry.key: value!});
```

```dart
class CartCheckbox extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CartCheckbox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final checkboxes = ref.watch(checkboxesProvider);

    return Column(
      children: [
        CheckboxListTile(
          title: const Text('Check all'),
          value: checkboxes.values.every((element) => element),
          onChanged: (bool? value) {
            ref.watch(checkboxesProvider.notifier).update((state) {
              return state.map((key, _) => MapEntry(key, value ?? false));
            });
          },
        ),
        ...checkboxes.entries.map(
          (entry) {
            return CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(entry.key),
              value: entry.value,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                ref.watch(checkboxesProvider.notifier).update((state) => {
                      ...state,
                      entry.key: value!,
                    });
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your time..
but.., I changed it a little, since I have it in different files
....something is not working right...
pressing any changes to the opposite value

Comment: I think it wont make any difference if you use the same provider.

Comment: Can you please tell me what options there are?  just if you do it through setState then everything works separately))

Comment: I am not sure about your context but you can share a dartpad link that will help me to understand your issue